# How to set a mouse to a particular cell in all worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set cursor/mouse pointer to cell `AL2` but my program can only make this on the active worksheet

```
Dim a As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Range("AL2").Select
Next Sheet
```

Could anyone explains why the code does not do what I would like to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
For Each aSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    aSheet.Activate
    Range("AL2").Select
Next Sheet
```

Having said that, one should always avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`

Why do you want to select a cell? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to learn the basics. I ordered a book this morning and waiting for it to be shipped to my house. I feel VBA for Excel really cool and useful things to know.

Comment: Just curious. Which book did you order?

Comment: Excel VBA Programming For Dummies: John Walkenbach - I am working in business field. Coding is far beyond what I do so needs something simple to start.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Out of curiosity: why should I avoid using .Select and .Activate? I can understand not using .Select (selecting a cell is not necessary 99% of the time), but what about .Activate?

Comment: Two Main reasons why .Select/.Activate/Selection should be avoided: 1) It slows down your code. 2) It is usually the main cause of runtime errors.